# In PowerShell, How to implement event handler for COM objects?

Tags: events, object, com, powershell, handler

I had a COM object created in PowerShell:
$CivicFactory = new-object -comObject LocationDisp.CivicAddressReportFactory

I need to implement the event handler for "NewCivicAddressReport". I tried this:

```
Register-ObjectEvent $CivicFactory -EventName "NewCivicAddressReport" -Action ({ echo "haha" })
```

But it gave me `"Register-ObjectEvent : Cannot register for event. An event with name 'NewCivicAddressReport' does not exist."`

Then I tried `$CivicFactory.add_NewCivicAddressRerport( {"haha"} )`

It did not work either: Method invocation failed because `[System.__ComObject#{bf773b93-c64f-4bee-beb2-67c0b8df66e0}] doesn't contain a method named 'add_NewCivicAddressRerport'`.

Can anyone tell me how to implement this event handler in PowerShell? Thanks in advance.
In VBScript it is as simple as

```
Function CivicFactory_NewCivicAddressReport(report)
    Blablabla...
End Function
```

But in PowerShell I couldn't get it working.

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in [PSEventing](http://pseventing.codeplex.com/), it adresses .NET, COM and WMI object event handling.

Comment: I would try `$CivicFactory | Get-Member -Type Event` to get all the events to which your object can be subscribed.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Interop assembly generated by Visual Studio.

Whenever a COM (library) reference is added to a C# project the IDE builds a wrapper that makes all entities, including events and enumerations, available to the .NET world.

The wrapper is usually packed in a file named like this:

```
Interop.<COM-library-name>.dll
```

Note that class names might be different. Use the IL Disassembler (ildasam.exe) to identify the class you have to instantiate.

Answer (score 0):

I tried Get-Member:`$CivicFactory | Get-Member -MemberType Event`
But it returned nothing.

If I run Get-Member without specifying member type, it does return its methods and properties. And the methods and properties work well so I believe the object is OK.

So it looks like the object's events are not recognized by the PowerShell system.

But the document states the event handler NewCivicAddressReport should be implemented, and I have done this successfully in VBScript and JScript.